# Mathematica DSolve input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

I'm trying to solve this differetial eqation.
dy/dx=3y^(2/3).

This is my input:
DSolve[{y'[x] = 3 y[x]^(2/3), y[2] = 0}, y[x], x]

This is my output:
DSolve::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of 3\ y[x]^(2/3) in the first argument {3\ y[x]^(2/3),0}."

I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

DSolve[{y'[x] **==** 3 y[x]^(2/3), y[2] = 0}, y[x], x] should be better, I presume ($==$ instead of $=$) ! You should get $$y(x)=x^3-6 x^2+12 x-8$$

Comment: this still gives me an error. and this output DSolve[{Derivative[1][y][x] == 3 y[x]^(2/3), 0}, y[x], x]